# How to retrieve one info from spinner (mysql_id)

Tags: android, spinner

First of all, stackoverflow is the website most accessed at my University =D.
Well, I have a spinner with some info (I am trying to do a message app). Let's see the code:

```
public void fillEmployee() {
    EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO(getBaseContext());
    spnDestinationMsg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnDestinationMsg);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY mysql_id ASC";

    Cursor cursor = dao.cacthByCursor(query);
    String[] from = { "mysql_id", "name" };
    int[] to = { R.id.txtMysql_Id_employee, R.id.txtName_employee };

    SimpleCursorAdapter ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_employee, cursor, from, to, 0);
    spnDestinationMsg.setAdapter(ad);}
```

Inside my object Employee I have the following fields:

```
    private long id;
    private long mysql_id;
    private String name;
    private int updatestatus;
```

---

Ok, now I must set the mysql_id to the employee object with the value coming from the spinner (the mysql_id comes from a webservice when I start the app for the first time). I need to get the mysql_id.

For example:

```
EmployeeDAO  emp1 =  new EmployeeDAO(getBaseContext());

emp1.setMySql_id(spnDestinationMsg.getAdapter().getItemId(spnDestinationMsg .getSelectedItemPosition()));
```

---

The problem I have is because the spinner just get the value of the array or the value of _id. I need to have access to the mysql_id.
How can I do this? Is there any way to access any data stored in the spinner. Because inside the cursor I selected everything from the table. How to access other values? If I want to catch the value of updatestatus for example? (I click the spinner item and I catch any value - mysql_id, _id, updatestatus, etc. Is it possible?).
PS: I would like to do it without using the OnSelectedListener because the user may not change the spinner.
Thanks for all help.

Comment: Is there any way to store and recover all the data inside the spinner? Is there an easy way? Sorry guys, I am having a lot of problems to adopt to android. I came from Windows development =) heuhauhauhau

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use a OnSelectedListener, despite your feelings about the user not making a change.

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
...

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
   }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
  }
}
```

If the user didn't actually change anything, the "OnNothingSelected" callback saves you

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin. Sorry but I did it here and it does not work.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "does not work".   The above is right out of the Android docs

Answer (score 0):

Create your Own Custom Adaptor for spinner

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

private Activity context;

public MySpinnerAdapter (Activity context){
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout item= (RelativeLayout)context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.<your spinner item layout name>, null); 

  //Your data to layout components

  item.setTag(<your tag object>);

    return item;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Swap-IOS-Android. Thanks for your answer. But do you have a simple way to do it? I am a beginner in android development and I really would like to use simple solutions now in the beginning. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole code:

```
public class MsgCadActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

private static final String PREF_NAME = "LoginActivityPreferences";
SharedPreferences sp;

static Spinner spnDestinoMsg;
static EditText txtAssuntoMsg;
static EditText txtMsg;
static Button btnEnviarMsg;
static Mensagem mensagem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_msg_cad);
    populaFuncionarioDestino();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

public void populaFuncionarioDestino() {
    FuncionarioDAO dao = new FuncionarioDAO(getBaseContext());
    spnDestinoMsg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnDestinoMsg);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM funcionario ORDER BY mysql_id ASC";

    Cursor cursor = dao.recuperarPorQueryCursor(query);
    String[] from = { "mysql_id", "nome" };
    int[] to = { R.id.txtMysql_Id_funcionario, R.id.txtNome_funcionario };

    SimpleCursorAdapter ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_funcionario, cursor, from, to, 0);
    spnDestinoMsg.setAdapter(ad);

}// endpopularFornecedor()

public void salvar(View v) {

    sp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Long funcionario_id = sp.getLong("funcionario_id", 0);      
    Log.d("MsgCadActivity ", " funcionario_id ->"+ funcionario_id.toString());
    // Linkar xml com objetos
    spnDestinoMsg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnDestinoMsg);
    txtAssuntoMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAssuntoMsg);
    txtMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    btnEnviarMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarMsg);

    mensagem = new Mensagem();

    // VALIDACOES
    if ((Util.validateNotNull(txtAssuntoMsg, "Preencha o Assunto!"))
            & (Util.validateNotNull(txtMsg, "Preencha a Mensagem!"))) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        mensagem.setAssunto(txtAssuntoMsg.getEditableText().toString());
        mensagem.setMsg(txtMsg.getEditableText().toString());
        mensagem.setFuncionario_origem_id(funcionario_id);          

        mensagem.setEnviado(currentDateandTime);

        MensagemDAO dao =  new MensagemDAO(getBaseContext());

        //dao.salvar(mensagem);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Mensagem enviada com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //dao.fecharConexao();
        //finish();
    }// end if

}// end salvarFM()

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

        int pos =  (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.d("MsgCadActivity ", " pos ->"+ pos);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: This part of the code is never reached:
int pos = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); Log.d("MsgCadActivity ", " pos ->"+ pos);